# Javascript Replace Regex - String with random number

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace a string that has a random number in it.

This is the string

```
[Async Chat Thread - #<randomNumber>/INFO]:
```

Here is what i have tried. the \d was one of my many attempts.

```
str.replace(/\[Async Chat Thread - #\d\/INFO\]:/gi, "");
```

I am very new to regex so if someone could please explain how i go about this or what i may be doing wrong.

Comment: `\d` matches a single digit. Do you want to match more than one digit?

Comment: yes, it is usually > 10

Comment: Then you need to specify repetition: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html .

Comment: That was easy, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\d` only matches a single digit. If you want to match one or more digits, you need to specify repetition. For example `+` denotes the occurrence of the previous group one ore more times:

```
\d+
```

OTOH, `{x, y}` specifies that the previous group has to occur at least `x` and at most `y` times:

```
\d{1,3}
```

[Learn more about repetition.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)